# Salesforce OAuth2 missing_oauth_token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am doing all the steps to gain an oauth token for salesforce but unable to workout the final step. I want to gather the Users information (email, first name, lastname, thumbnail).

So I get to the step where I can get this information :

```
<OAuth>
<id>
   https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000qdxPEAQ/00590000001hbAyAAI
</id>
<issued_at>1386648423427</issued_at>
<scope>id chatter_api</scope>
<instance_url>https://ap1.salesforce.com</instance_url>
<signature>YlnejSL3ZKkSmbnt916sLZuzt13UNUFGi+kGCjU7ql0=</signature>
<access_token>
00D90000000qdxP!AQsAQIcR.oo6y.EDuf3B4fzctQ2e7DK0L1kGjgxGSl.dBgetu3lUbZp.VDZjSIi7O1LXmTMWFZmOJVeRS.IQfvPL8VmhxLaC
</access_token>
</OAuth>
```

but from here, I am not sure how to get the users information (returned as XML or JSON).
From a browser, can't I go to https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ  followed by some auth key?  (I dont have CURL installed).

Whenever I try go to this in the URL it states

```
   Missing_OAuth_Token
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to develop something using Google OAuth,so I tried request like `https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ?access_token=access_token`(this format is supported by [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=zh-CN)), but unfortunately I get response "Missing_OAuth_Token", just like what you did. Then I refer to [salesforce document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=quickstart_oauth.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/quickstart_oauth.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), and found that it only support the format like:

`curl https://instance_name.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'`

You need to put access_token in the header of the request, so install CURL, or send the request in your program with access_token in header.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right tracks, you can do a GET on the id URL, but you need to supply the access token in the Authorization header, e.g. `Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}`